# import {Values} from 'redux-form-website-template'

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form in my web app and I would like to display the values of my form.

In order to do this I used the Values field of the redux-form-website-template package.

This is the same package that redux-form uses on their sample website:
https://codesandbox.io/s/PNQYw1kVy

In their example, they are using version 0.0.41 of the redux-form-website-template package.

If I nom install --save 'redux-form-website-template'@0.0.41 
Then the app works but with a warning about using propTypes being deprecated etc....

If I install the latest version of 'redux-form-website-template' then I get the following error when I `import {Values} from 'redux-form-website-template'`

The error is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined

Is there a work around here?
or should I just use version 0.0.41

Basically I would like a convenient way to display the state of my form as it is being field up by the user, just like in the sandbox.

This is my code which should not have any problems since using the old version works:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import {Values} from 'redux-form-website-template'

import showResults from "./showResults";
import BirthChartForm from './BirthChartForm'
import InitializeFromStateForm from "./InitializeFromStateForm";



class App extends Component {

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>EXAMPLE</h1>
        <BirthChartForm/>
        <Values form="birthchartform" />
      </div>

    )

  }
}

function mapStateToProps() {

  return {

  }
}

export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(App))
```